# How to properly input character vector

Tags: r, vector

I've been toiling away for hours creating this list of variable values that will need modification, but when I try to save it as a vector I get an error message:

```
c("Athens and Higher TEI of Crete", "Athens U Economics and Business","Australian Department of Climate Change and Energy Efficiency","Beijing U Aeronautics and Astronautics","Cambridge Centre for Economic and Public Policy","Center for Agricultural and Rural Development","Center for Strategic Management and Globalization","Centers for Disease Control and Prevention","Centre of Full Employment and Equity","Central Taiwan U Science and Technology","Centre for Econometrics and Allied Research","Centre for Industrial Relations and Human Resources","Centre of Excellence for Science and Innovation Studies","Centre for the Study of Globalisation and Regionalisation","College of William and Mary","ESMT European School of Management and Technology”,"Davis and Giannini Foundation”,"Davis and Giannini Foundation of Agricultural Economics”,"Dubai Chamber of Commerce and Industry”,"Federal Urdu U Arts, Science and Technology”,"Financial and Economic Research Center”,"Franklin and Marshall College”,"Graduate Institute of Finance and Banking”,"Hong Kong U Science and Technology”,"IN+ Center for Innovation, Technology, and Policy Research”,"Institute of Business and Management”,"Insper Instituet of Education and Research, Sao Paulo”,"Institute for Food and Resource Economics”,"Institute of Economics and Industrial Engineering”,"Institute of Finance and Accounting”,"Institute of Food and Resource Economics”,"Institute of Physical Planning and Information”,"Institute of Social and Economic Research”,"Institute of Statistical, Social and Economic Research”,"Institute for Economics and Business Administration”,"International Journal of Applied Economics and Econometrics”,"Jinwen U Science and Technology”,"Kazakhstan Institute of Management, Economics and Strategic Research”,"King Fahd U Petroleum and Minerals”,"Lille I U, Science and Technology”,"Maldives Ministry of Economic Development and Trade”,"Melbourne Institute of Applied Economic and Social Research”,"Mendel U Agriculture and Forestry”,"National Institute of Economic and Social Research”,"National Kaohsiung First U Science and Technology”,"National Pingtung U Science and Technology”,"National School of Political and Administrative Studies”,"National School of Political Studies and Public Administration”,"National Yunlin U Science and Technology”,"Norwegian School of Economics and Business Administration”,"Phoenix Center for Advanced Legal and Economic Public Policy Studies”,"Research Centre for Education and the Labour Market”,"Research Institute of Economics and Management”,"Research Institute for Economics and Business Administration”,"Research Institute for Labor Economics and Labor Law”,"Rennes and Agrocampus Ouest, Rennes”,"Romanian Ministry of Administration and Interior”,"Romanian Ministry of Education, Research, Youth and Sports”,"Shanghai U Finance and Economics”,"Sungard Trading and Risk Systems”,"Takming U Science and Technology”,"Theoretical and Applied Economics”,"U Petroleum and Energy Studies, Dehradun”,"UN Food and Agriculture Organization”,"US Department of Health and Human Services”,"Wind Science and Engineering Research Center”,
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "re for Industrial Relations and Human Resources","Centre of Excellence for Science and Innovation Studies","Centre for the Study of Globalisation and Regionalisation","College of William and M"
>   "West Central Research and Extension Center”)

I can find no "unexpected symbols" anywhere, I deleted all rowbreaks prior to posting this question, and i copied my text to notepad++ for good measure. Why does the program insist on giving me grief?

Comment: Try checking your quotes. Some are off or wrap everything in `''`.

Comment: Your posted code has a comma at the end and is missing a parenthesis at the end.

Comment: do not use `smart quotes` (curly quotes) and missing parenthesis at the end - take a look at the quotes at the end of `"ESMT European School of Management and Technology”`

Comment: @Monk thats a misquote on my part in that case, the results are the same if the comma is deleted and the end of the parenthesis is there.

Comment: Where is this  data from? Is it copied and pasted from some browser? What's the encoding?

Comment: This is originally from a list of ca 500 csv files which I had to concatanate with bash and then process further with R.  I have no Idea of the previous or current encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your quotes issue in the code below.

```
c("Athens and Higher TEI of Crete", "Athens U Economics and Business","Australian Department of Climate Change and Energy Efficiency","Beijing U Aeronautics and Astronautics","Cambridge Centre for Economic and Public Policy","Center for Agricultural and Rural Development","Center for Strategic Management and Globalization","Centers for Disease Control and Prevention","Centre of Full Employment and Equity","Central Taiwan U Science and Technology","Centre for Econometrics and Allied Research","Centre for Industrial Relations and Human Resources","Centre of Excellence for Science and Innovation Studies","Centre for the Study of Globalisation and Regionalisation","College of William and Mary","ESMT European School of Management and Technology","Davis and Giannini Foundation","Davis and Giannini Foundation of Agricultural Economics","Dubai Chamber of Commerce and Industry","Federal Urdu U Arts, Science and Technology","Financial and Economic Research Center","Franklin and Marshall College","Graduate Institute of Finance and Banking","Hong Kong U Science and Technology","IN+ Center for Innovation, Technology, and Policy Research","Institute of Business and Management","Insper Instituet of Education and Research, Sao Paulo","Institute for Food and Resource Economics","Institute of Economics and Industrial Engineering","Institute of Finance and Accounting","Institute of Food and Resource Economics","Institute of Physical Planning and Information","Institute of Social and Economic Research","Institute of Statistical, Social and Economic Research","Institute for Economics and Business Administration","International Journal of Applied Economics and Econometrics","Jinwen U Science and Technology","Kazakhstan Institute of Management, Economics and Strategic Research","King Fahd U Petroleum and Minerals","Lille I U, Science and Technology","Maldives Ministry of Economic Development and Trade","Melbourne Institute of Applied Economic and Social Research","Mendel U Agriculture and Forestry","National Institute of Economic and Social Research","National Kaohsiung First U Science and Technology","National Pingtung U Science and Technology","National School of Political and Administrative Studies","National School of Political Studies and Public Administration","National Yunlin U Science and Technology","Norwegian School of Economics and Business Administration","Phoenix Center for Advanced Legal and Economic Public Policy Studies","Research Centre for Education and the Labour Market","Research Institute of Economics and Management","Research Institute for Economics and Business Administration","Research Institute for Labor Economics and Labor Law","Rennes and Agrocampus Ouest, Rennes","Romanian Ministry of Administration and Interior","Romanian Ministry of Education, Research, Youth and Sports","Shanghai U Finance and Economics","Sungard Trading and Risk Systems","Takming U Science and Technology","Theoretical and Applied Economics","U Petroleum and Energy Studies, Dehradun","UN Food and Agriculture Organization","US Department of Health and Human Services","Wind Science and Engineering Research Center")
```